# Shall I always use a database in Enterprise applications (.war, .ear - essentially .jar) and never write to a file?

Tags: java, enterprise

If I have a resource file (mydata.txt) in resources folder (set up as another source folder) of my application. This mydata.txt eventually would be packaged inside root of a jar file (.war) to be deployed to some application server (Tomcat, Jetty, WildFly).

File mydata.txt has some crucial data needed to the application, and this file shall be appended by the application.

To get a file from jar I can use getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mydata.txt") - thus I get this file as InputStream. But there is no way I can get this file as OutputStream and write to it.

All solutions with getClass().getResource() - returning URL are discouraged, getResourceAsStream is always recommended, but it allows only reading, not writing/updating/appending the file.

getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() solution is also discouraged to get (write) access to the file.

I could create some file in a temporary directory on Tomcat Server (System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") and write to it, but it is nonsense because this file contents is crucial for the application (to write it to tmp dir), besides I need to append file, not create a new one and write to it.

Also, **I am not sure that writing to any other directory (other than tmp) of application server is a good idea (please correct me if I am wrong here).**

So **I come to the conclusion that it is not recommended to save any data to a file in enterprise application, so I shall always use a database instead?**

Comment: After listing all those flaws with an attempted file based approach, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Yes. Beside all you mentioned (which is all correct) the biggest problems are

- concurrent access
- transaction handling

which both a database serves perfect and with a file approach is just a pain in the ****

In addition to that especially an application server provides you with configuration of connection (and pools) to data sources of any kind, which is really handy in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Could you please give a hint what "configuration of connection" means - what to google for or to read about? Googling just "configuration of connection" did not help unfortunately...

Comment: Sure: "<app-server e.g. glassfish> jdbc connection pool configuration". Here are some screenshots to help you http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Glassfish/How_to_set_up_a_Connection_Pool

Comment: Just as a note: You gain access to that datasource via JNDI (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4725/abmdz/index.html)